# HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization - PSQLException

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, docker

I am trying to learn the basics of springboot using a linkedin learning video:

#### Background/Setup:

- OS: MacOSX Mojave 10.14.6
- Java:

  - OpenJDK 13.0.2 2020-01-14
  - OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 13.0.2+8)
  - OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 13.0.2+8, mixed mode,sharing)
- IDE: Intellij Ultimate
- Docker: Docker version 19.03.5, build 633a0ea
- Postgres/psql - psql (PostgreSQL) 12.2

The project was setup using Spring-initializr. There is a shell script that initiates docker with postgres and inserts data into tables. I have verified this by accessing the docker manually and connecting to the DB

#### application.properties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
logging.level.org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils=debug
logging.level.org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.LobCreatorBuilderImpl=error


spring.jpa.database=postgresql
spring.datasource.platform=postgres
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dev
spring.datasouce.username=postgres
spring.datasouce.password=postgres
```

#### Issue

When I run the application, I get an error

```
2020-03-24 18:55:59.213 ERROR 1785 --- [main]
com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool     initialization.
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The server requested password-based authentication, but no password was provided.
at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:544) ~[postgresql-42.2.10.jar:42.2.10]
at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:145) ~[postgresql-42.2.10.jar:42.2.10]
at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:196) ~[postgresql-42.2.10.jar:42.2.10]
at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49) ~[postgresql-42.2.10.jar:42.2.10]
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:211) ~[postgresql-42.2.10.jar:42.2.10]
at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:459) ~[postgresql-42.2.10.jar:42.2.10]
at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:261) ~[postgresql-42.2.10.jar:42.2.10]
```

the shell script is as follows

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -euo pipefail
which psql > /dev/null || (echoerr "Please ensure that postgres client is in your PATH" && exit 1)

mkdir -p "$HOME/docker/volumes/postgres"
rm -rf "$HOME/docker/volumes/postgres/data"

docker run --rm --name pg-docker -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres -e POSTGRES_DB=dev -d -p 5432:5432 -v $HOME/docker/volumes/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql postgres
sleep 3
export PGPASSWORD=postgres
psql -U postgres -d dev -h localhost -f schema.sql
psql -U postgres -d dev -h localhost -f data.sql
```

I am not sure how the password is passed on to ConnectionFactoryImpl.java

I would appreciate it if anyone could help me fix this issue.

Comment: What's your DB setup in `application.properties`?

Comment: Updated the question with `application.properties`

Comment: You got typo `spring.datasouce.` instead of `spring.datasource.` for both username & password.

Comment: Thanks that worked like a charm. TY @StefanGolubović